# How to remove delimiter in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have following data and have to ingest it into hive table:-

`2,5621 WOMEN’S READY TO WEAR STORES`

how can I remove "’" from women’s because I am getting output like mentioned below:

"`2 5621 WOMEN�S READY TO WEAR STORES`"

how to deal with '�'.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `regexp_replace()` function.
Example of this:

```
regexp_replace("foobar", "oo|ar", "")
```

results `fb`

The parameters look like this:

`regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string REPLACEMENT)`

More about this and user-defined functions(UDF) [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Comment: so I need to run regexp_replace with select statement , but what if I want to replace it permanently, how I can save that.

Comment: By creating a new table if possible.